# Laravel Validate Against Auth::user()->id;

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to avoid the paradox of admin remove its own admin role and got this error

`Undefined variable: request`

`Undefined variable: thisUser`

the variable is defined outside of the validation function,

below is the entire validation code, is there a way to do this with built-in validation?

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{

$thisUser = Auth::user();

$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|alpha_num',
        'email' => 'required|E-Mail',
        'is_admin' => [
            'required', 
            'boolean', 
            function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if($thisUser->id == $request->input('id')) {
                    return $fail('Can not remove admin privilege of yourself');
                }
            }
        ]
    ]);

    ... 
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to perform this? Also, did you include the Auth and Request facades in the namespace?

Comment: this is in a controller class, and yes everything is included, all variable works outside of the validate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure won't have access to the variables defined outside its scope.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'id' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required|alpha_num',
    'email' => 'required|E-Mail',
    'is_admin' => [
        'required', 
        'boolean', 
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) use($thisUser, $request) {
            if($thisUser->id == $request->input('id')) {
                return $fail('Can not remove admin privilege of yourself');
            }
        }
    ]
]);
```

This should work.